# Algorithm to detect photo orientation

Tags: image, image-processing, orientation, heuristics

I would like to rotate photos automatically, even when EXIF metadata about the image orientation is not available.

Are there any good algorithms for detecting the orientation of a photo?  The images are photographs from a digital camera. The algorithm doesn't have to work perfectly, but any reduction in the amount of human interaction required to properly rotate photos would be a benefit.

I have found these two papers on the topic:

- [Pre-Classification for Automatic Image Orientation](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/Xplore/login.jsp?url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fiel5%2F11024%2F34758%2F01660295.pdf%3Farnumber%3D1660295&authDecision=-203) (2006)
- [A Probabilistic Approach to Image Orientation Detection via Confidence-Based Integration of Low-Level and Semantic Cues](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/Xplore/login.jsp?url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fiel5%2F9515%2F30163%2F01384938.pdf%3Farnumber%3D1384938&authDecision=-203) (2004)

Pointers to other research and especially implementations are appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be an algorithm for auto vertical/horizontal orientation, but it is the closest algorithm I could found with some implementations out there: deskew. Check ImageMagick deskew, or: http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?ct=rc#f0yt7jaEG7A/raster/deskewer.cpp

Comment: You may also be interested in that people are considering the trick of rotating images as a new style of CAPTCHA.  A small circular image is presented with an obvious (to us) object, but no clear horizon.  I realize this doesn't help you, but it does underscore the depth of the problem. 

http://www.richgossweiler.com/projects/rotcaptcha/rotcaptcha.pdf

Comment: @Luke Francl, i want to do a similar thing, so what did finally work out for you?

Comment: @eSKay - nothing yet. I have left the question open in case there is something great out there. @smackfu has the best suggestion I think but there's nothing off-the-shelf to implement it. You'd have to write it yourself. I don't have a great need for this functionality right now so I haven't pressed further.

Comment: Do you just want to detect which of the four edges of the image to choose as the top? Or do you want to be able to select any rotation throughout the 360 degrees? I can imagine there would be different approaches/algorithsm for the two cases.

Comment: I'm in the same position as you, only 8 years later ;- ) . Lots of stuff out there, I'm going to try `exiftrans` w Ubuntu. Did you see this paper?  http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~guerzhoy/oriviz/crv17.pdf ? They clain 90%+ success on a multi-thousand picture set of end-user camera photos. (the example fail is very funny). Good luck!

Answer (score 9):

Many photographs from consumer digital cameras are of people, which could be used for orientation.  Face detection is a well-studied research area.  Basic face detection would give you a rectangle whose longer side should be the vertical dimension.  Further, if you can detect the eyes/mouth, you should be able to pick the correct orientation of the rectangle.

Many other photographs are tourist snaps, where the sky is up and blue, and the ground is down and green.

Comment: Many face detection algorithms will not find faces that are upside down so you have to look for faces in all four possible directions.

Comment: This is something that I've been considering since examining the papers I linked to above, because at least one of them uses face recognition as part of the algorithm. Since the vast majority of my photo corpus will include faces I think it may work well (assuming I can find a face recognition program that can recognize orientation, per Janusz).

Comment: Many (most?) tourist snaps with sky in them have a white sky due to overexposure of the sky needed to properly expose the much darker main subject.

Comment: Good idea, but lots of photos don't have people in them!

Answer (score 4):

I could only find http://sourceforge.net/projects/rotator/.

I used a test set of holiday photos comprising 70 pictures with about 18 requiring rotation.

After processing with the default settings, there were 20 that were either rotated or not rotated in error.

Not so great a result.

Comment: Thanks for the user report!

Answer (score 0):

If the images are not square, you may be able to make the assumption that the default images are wider than they are tall.
If that's the case determaning whether you need to rotate is just a matter of comparing the aspect ratio and rotating to reorient to default.  Though you may end up with upside down images.

Comment: This is only true for default images. Often people taking pictures of faces or people will turn the camera...

Comment: True, but when people turn the camera to take such pictures, unless the faces are sideways or upside down, you may be able to use the aspect ratio for at least a hint.

Comment: This is not true. Every object can be photographed in portrait or landscape orientation. And based on my images the ration is 60:40 (landscape to portrait). And if I have square image it will be because of postprocessing, not by camera.

Comment: @Janusz, it depend a lot. You will find amazing portraits in landscape orientation