# What side is up? - Automatic Image rotation algorithm

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

Software like Google Picasa demonstrate very well that software can figure out which way a photo was taken without Exif-Data as it is not available in every camera.

Is there a documented algorithm which outputs whether or not an image has to be rotated or not?
I want to find out the rotation without the use of EXIF Data.  If at all possible I would want to do this with ImageMagick.

Comment: Have you seen any examples for which Picasa does not yield the correct result? Have you tried loading synthetic images to see how Picasa handles them? Also, could you post a few sample images?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1141928

Comment: I found several papers (and the above duplicate) with the google query "image orientation detection algorithm".

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is a complex problem and subject to ongoing research accordingly. [Yann's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9120706/45773) is basically pointing towards the usual approaches already (+1) and [mfrellum's hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9148722/45773) towards the subject of *Pattern Recognition* likewise applies as well (+1) - for a more in depth analysis you might want to read through a couple of the following papers (subjective selection from past research of mine):

[Please note: most of the PDF links below have been deduced from [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/) - Google is naturally good at finding the matching PDF elsewhere for publicly available abstracts of papers, where the actual content is more often than not hidden behind paywalls. The legality of this is subject to heated discussions of course, and so is shielding regularly publicly financed scientific research like so in the first place - make your own judgement!]

- One of the older and most widely cited papers is probably [Automatic Image Orientation Detection](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=68804) (*Hongjiang Zhang, Aditya Vailaya, and Anil Jain* - 1999).

  - A more elaborate, but less official update from 2002 is currently available as an [IEEE Proof PDF](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.10.2068&rep=rep1&type=pdf).
- One of *Hongjiang Zhang* many follow up papers is [Content-Based Image Orientation Detection with Support Vector Machines](http://nguyendangbinh.org/Proceedings/CVPR/2001/CD4/CBAIVL/wang_y_NEW.pdf) (*Yongmei Wang and  Hongjiang Zhan* - 2001)
- Another (though less illustrative) one is [Boosting Image Orientation Detection with Indoor vs. Outdoor Classification](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leizhang/paper/wacv02.pdf) (*Lei Zhang, Mingjing Li, Hongjiang Zhang - 2002)*

  - See e.g. coauthor Lei Zhang's [Microsoft Research Publications](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/leizhang/publications.aspx) to get an idea of the many image related algorithmic challenges eventually involved here one way or another as well ;)
- Accordingly, a summary of the aforementioned approaches is [Detecting image orientation based
  on low-level visual content](http://noodle.med.yale.edu/~wang/Research/cviu04_wang.pdf) (*Yongmei Michelle Wang and Hongjiang Zhang* - 2003)
- A quite sophisticated one is [A Probabilistic Approach to Image Orientation Detection via Confidence-Based Integration of Low-Level and Semantic Cues](http://nguyendangbinh.org/Proceedings/CVPR/2004/DATA/MDDE_05.PDF) (*Jiebo Luo and Matthew Boutel - 2004*)
- The best match regarding your question title is actually [Image orientation detection with integrated human perception cues (or *which way is up*)](http://cygnus-x1.cs.duke.edu/~lxia/Files/ICIP03.pdf) (*Lei Wang, Xu Liu, Lirong Xia, Guangyou Xu, Alfred Bruckstein - 2003*) ;)
- Finally, you might want to have a look at a respective patent regarding a [system and method for automatic digital photo orientation detection](http://www.google.com/patents/US20090257682?dq=image%20orientation%20detection) (*2008*) - the basic algorithm is summarized with great detail in [Figure 8](http://www.google.com/patents?id=7ifJAAAAEBAJ&pg=PA5&dq=image%20orientation%20detection&source=gbs_selected_pages&cad=2#v=onepage&q=image%20orientation%20detection&f=false) ;)

Unfortunately I'm not aware of any readily available implementations/libraries, though I'd be surprised if there wouldn't be a few bits available at least.

Have fun :)

Answer (score 15):

It probably reads the [exif information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) stored in the jpg header, when that's available. This gives the orientation of the camera when the photo was taken. This is a far simpler approach than trying to analyse the photo to see which way is up.

There are [eight possible orientations](http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/exif-orientation.html). The flags tell you which way is up:

```
EXIF Orientation Value  Row #0 is:  Column #0 is:
1                       Top         Left side
2*                      Top         Right side
3                       Bottom      Right side
4*                      Bottom      Left side
5*                      Left side   Top
6                       Right side  Top
7*                      Right side  Bottom
8                       Left side   Bottom

NOTE: Values with "*" are uncommon since they represent "flipped" orientations.
```

This will reduce the number of photos where image recognition has to be used.

Comment: NOTE: I added this answer **before** the question was updated to specify that EXIF information wasn't always available.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know of a specific implementation, but here are some thoughts:

1. The sky is blue. Look for blue along an edge. More blue = more likely to be up.
2. The upper regions of an image tend have less detail (sky, clouds) than lower regions.
3. Do an edge detection and look for long horizontal lines. If they're not horizontal, its possible the image is on its side. Combine with #1 and #2 to see if you are 180 degrees out or not.

Note that there is a rotation field in the EXIF data, which is from the camera's orientation sensor. Always use this data first, as the rest is an image processing guess.

Answer (score 5):

I don't  know a ready made solution for this problem but it is a classification problem and there are many classic algorithms that can be used.
[Pattern Recognition and Neural Networks](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521717701) by B.D. Ripley is a good read on the subject.

openCV has a [machine learning](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/ml/doc/ml.html) module that can be used for this.

The solution will probably involve heuristics like 1-3 in Yann Ramin's answer but quantified as numbers between 0 and 1 and put in a vector. You can use imags with exif data about orientation to make a training set for the classifier.

Answer (score 4):

Dominant light sources are usually up, whether or not it is night or day, and whether or not there are people in the scene. Combining highlight detection with edge detection you can identify likely locations of the scene's light sources and judge which way is up.

**EDIT**: Great question - I just spent 5 minutes on Google Scholar and failed to even find the correct problem domain.

**EDIT**: Got it. It's called 'image orientation detection' -- not too obscure a title.

**EDIT**: A quick review suggests that there are two major approaches:

1. Combined classifiers - train lots of different classifiers and combine the results, a classic 'throw everything you got at it' shotgun approach. Here, most of the innovative contribution of papers appears to be on how to design new ways for different classifiers to be combined.
2. Specific features - pick a specific (or small set of specific) feature and use these to classify, detect orientation. Some examples are : facial recognition + edge detection, local binary pattern overlap (relative: only works between two images of same subject).

Anyway it is certainly an interesting field, and there seem to be more patents than papers, which makes it even more interesting. However I did not find anything that explicates the Picasa method. However I did find this:

S. Baluja (from Google) has published the following papers:

- [Automated image-orientation detection: a scalable boosting approach](http://www.springerlink.com/content/n7066310612j5g42/), 2007
- [Efficient face-orientation detection](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/usr/har/Web/icip2004.pdf), 2004
- [What's up CAPTCHA?: a CAPTCHA based on image orientation](http://www2009.eprints.org/85/1/p841.pdf), 2009

From this, one might conclude that the methods therein are indicative of what Google uses.

Answer (score 0):

Picasa has facial recognition, which may be helping even if it's not actually tagging known people.